# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation during migration in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, migration

I have a problem while migrating

`Migration File`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterTableMm extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('downloads', function($table){

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title',255);
            $table->string('count',45)->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();


            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        });


        Schema::table('marketing_materials', function($table)
        {

            $table->string('download_total', 45 )->default(0);
            $table->integer('download_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('download_id')->references('id')->on('downloads');


        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign('users_user_id_foreign');

        });

        Schema::drop('downloads');


        Schema::table('marketing_materials', function($table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign('marketing_materials_download_id_foreign');

        });

        Schema::table('marketing_materials', function($table)
        {

            $table->dropColumn('download_total');
            $table->dropColumn('download_id');


        });
    }

}
```

`Error Message`

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`distributor-local`.`#sql-668_3d`, CONSTRAINT `marketing_mater
  ials_download_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`download_id`) REFERENCES `downloads` (`id`)) (SQL: alter table `marketing_materials` add constraint marketing_materials_download_id_foreign fo
  reign key (`download_id`) references `downloads` (`id`))


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`distributor-local`.`#sql-668_3d`, CONSTRAINT `marketing_mater
  ials_download_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`download_id`) REFERENCES `downloads` (`id`))
```

I have all the required  tables

- users
- marketing_materials
- I just recently migrate my downloads table

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong ?

The part that confuse me the most of that error message is that, all the contents are added the database fine. See the picture below

[image]

I also alter my marketing_materials table, and that's also work.

[image]

Should I just ignore the error message ???

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? I had problems with migrations too and sometimes I resolved putting `unsignedInteger` instead of `integer('name')->unsigned()`. Other times i just rollback the migrations, dump the autoload files from composer and run the migrations singularly

Comment: I am running Laravel 4.2